# SQL: get data spread over 3 tables

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to get some statistics for an online game I maintain. I am searching for an SQL statement to get the result on the bottom.

There are three tables:

A table with teams, each having a unique identifier.

```
table teams
---------------------
| teamid | teamname |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | team_a   |
| 2      | team_x   |
---------------------
```

A table with players, each having a unique identifier and optionally an affiliation to one team by it's unique teamid.

```
table players
--------------------------------
| playerid | teamid | username |
|----------|--------|----------|
| 1        | 1      | user_a   |
| 2        |        | user_b   |
| 3        | 2      | user_c   |
| 4        | 2      | user_d   |
| 5        | 1      | user_e   |
--------------------------------
```

Finally a table with events. The event (duration in seconds) is related to one of the players through their playerid.

```
table events.
-----------------------
| playerid | duration |
|----------|----------|
| 1        | 2        |
| 2        | 5        |
| 3        | 3        |
| 4        | 8        |
| 5        | 12       |
| 3        | 4        |
-----------------------
```

I am trying to get a result where the durations of all team members is summed up.

```
result
--------------------------
| teamid | SUM(duration) |
|--------|---------------|
| 1      | 14            | (2+12)
| 2      | 15            | (3+8+4)
--------------------------
```

I tried several combinations of UNION, WHERE IN, JOIN and GROUP but could not get it right. I am using PostgreSQL and PHP. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sum` with `group by`:

```
select t.teamid, sum(e.duration)
from team t
   join players p on t.teamid = p.teamid
   join events e on p.playerid = e.playerid
group by t.teamid
```

If you need all teams to be returned even if they don't have events, then use an `outer join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT teamid, Sum(duration), 
    AS LineItemAmount, AccountDescription
FROM teams
    JOIN teams ON teams.teamid = players.teamid
    JOIN events ON players.playersid = events.playersid
    JOIN GLAccounts ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
    GROUP BY teamid
```

http://www.w3computing.com/sqlserver/inner-joins-join-two-tables/